# How do i pass a function as a parameter in dart?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, widget

Code down here keeps telling me that there's a problem in the syntax here `onTap: onPress,`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Function? onPress;
  ReusableCard({ this.cardChild, required this.color, this.onPress});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        child: cardChild,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use voidcallback

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final VoidCallback onPress;//here
  ReusableCard({ this.cardChild, required this.color, this.onPress});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        child: cardChild,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or you can also do this

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Function? onPress;
  ReusableCard({ this.cardChild, required this.color, this.onPress});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){onPress();},//create a method and call onPress here
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        child: cardChild,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `final Function? onPress;` is defined nullable function.

But `onTap` requires void function,

You can just do

```dart
  final Function()? onPress;
```

Or

```dart
onTap: () {
    if (onPress != null) onPress!();
  },
```

Using `VoidCallback`

```dart
/// Signature of callbacks that have no arguments and return no data.
typedef VoidCallback = void Function();
```

Hope you get the issue here. Also provide key on constructor.

```dart
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Function()? onPress;
  const ReusableCard({
    this.cardChild,
    required this.color,
    this.onPress,
    super.key,
  });
```

But I think it is pretty to use `final GestureTapCallback? onPress;`

Answer (score 1):

Function is null type, so it can be null.

You should write

```
onTap:(onPress!=null) ? onPress : null
```